# How to prevent QtCreator from moving breakpoints, make all lines available?

Tags: c++, debugging, qt-creator, breakpoints

I'm trying to debug [Cataclysm-DDA](https://github.com/CleverRaven/Cataclysm-DDA/), a FOSS game, in QtCreator. It worked great at first, I just had to open it through the `CMakeLists.txt` import, set the `TILES` varialble to `ON` and select the `cataclysm-tiles` executable.

But when I tried to set breakpoints they sometimes move down to the point where they are useless. For example [this line](https://github.com/CleverRaven/Cataclysm-DDA/blob/92e150734cfb30802c3876adb92beeffa62996f4/src/mapbuffer.cpp#L296). I can set the breakpoint inside that function but not on that exact line, it gets moved down 5 lines where it no longer catches anything.

`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is already set to `Debug`, what else can be done? I've just installed it on a relatively clean system on an old machine so everything should be default.

Comment: Whenever I get such problems with Qt Creator, I run `Rebuild All` from the `Build` menu. Does this help?

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving breakpoints is usually a sign of optimization (since some lines are optimized out).  Setting the build type to Debug should prevent all optimization but...

If you are using the same build directory for release and Debug (or even if not) go into the build directory and delete everything, then rerun CMake and build again.  Sometimes old targets (which may have optimization) aren't automatically rebuilt.

Comment: I'll try removing everything in the build dir but I'm quite sure that QtCreator already did that or at least something similar because I had to compile everything again after changes. Anyway, will be back after several hours (the machine is quite slow and 4G RAM is not enough so it goes to swap a lot).

Comment: Usually clearing the build dir doesn't fix things, but sometimes it does help so I've gotten into a habit of it, especially when changing build parameters!  Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Oh, and this likely isn't the issue, but I'll mention it -- breakpoints moving can also be related to the source code loaded by the debugger not matching the compiled target.  This is very unlikely if you are compiling in Qt since it will automatically find the sources.

Comment: @int_ua: Instead of clearing the build dir, you can just run `Rebuild All` from the `Build` menu. That's what I do, anyway.

Comment: @int_ua: Does it really take *several hours* to build? If this is anything like a serious project, you need to fix that first.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help, thank you for trying to help. The code didn't change for many builds now, I'm just getting familiar with QtCreator for now. I assume that deleting everything and building again is at least as resetting as `Rebuild All`. Yes, it's a large game, you can check it by the link in the OP, but it's ok for me as I don't intend to rebuild it over and over. When I change just one file it takes just some minutes to build. And it's not something important, I just leave it there to build and do other things.